Python to PostgreSQL Connection - OSError for TLS CA Certificate, how do I set up proper path for pip install?
Good evening, I am new to Python so apologies for the newb question. I am attempting to install two pips, postgres and psycopg2, beginning with postgres. In cmd, I use the following:
` pip install postgres`

This returns "ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: Could not find a suitable TLS CA certificate bundle, invalid path: "C:\Users\USERNAME\CodePractice\cacert.pem"
And "WARNING: There was an error checking the latest version of pip."
I am running Python 3.12.3 on Windows 11 64-bit. Pip3.exe is installed and pip.ini is in my AppData\Roaming reading "[global] cert = path\to\cacert.pem". I cannot find pip directories in any other location.
I first tried downloading a new cacert.pem and plugging its path into the system variable CURL_CA_BUNDLE no avail.
Afterward I uninstalled and reinstalled Python and PyCharm making sure to check "Add python.exe to PATH".
Pip3.exe is present and pip.ini has its default values. When running pip config -v list I get:
 For variant 'global', will try loading 'C:\ProgramData\pip\pip.ini'
 For variant 'user', will try loading 'C:\Users\USERNAME\pip\pip.ini'
 For variant 'user', will try loading 'C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\pip\pip.ini'
 For variant 'site', will try loading 'C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\pip.ini'

global.cert='path\to\cacert.pem'
When running pip config -v debug I get:
 [The above]
 env_var:
 env:
 global:
      C:\ProgramData\pip\pip.ini, exists: False
 site:
      C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\pip.ini, exists: False
 user:
      C:\Users\USERNAME\pip\pip.ini, exists: False
      C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\pip\pip.ini, exists TRUE
           global.cert: path\to\cacert.pem

Other users I have seen with similar issues said they deleted or reset the value of a system variable named REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE but this is not present on my system.
What is the fix for this, and if it's not too much to ask, could you explain why this is a problem? It is interesting to learn about. Thank you!
